# SectionHeader tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Tenho uma Tableview de mensagens, gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar sections usando o campo date do objeto NotificationItem.

```
struct NotificationItem: Codable {
let title: String
let body: String
let date: Date
let link: String
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if notificationStore.items.count == 0 {
        self.viewSemNotificacoes.isHidden = false
    } else {
        self.viewSemNotificacoes.isHidden = true
    }
    return notificationStore.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let newsCell = cell as? NotificationItemTableViewCell {
        newsCell.updateWithNewsItem(notificationStore.items[indexPath.row])
    }

    return cell
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar SectionHeader usando o campo date mesmo sem este objeto possuir um array de sections. Já inseri sections em tableviews mas sempre usando o array que continha dentro do objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não implementou o método numberOfSectionsInTableView:, a tableView tem por padrão uma seção e 'n' células, onde 'n' é o número de elementos no array 'notificationStore.items'. Usando essa mesma estrutura de dados, você poderia criar uma tableView com 'n' seções, cada qual com uma célula:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return notificationStore.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: notificationStore.items[section].date)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let newsCell = cell as? NotificationItemTableViewCell {
        newsCell.updateWithNewsItem(notificationStore.items[indexPath.section])
    }

    return cell
}
```

Caso você precise multiplas seções e também mostrar multiplas mensagem numa mesma seção, o array unidimensional não atende suas necessidades. Nesse caso você precisaria de uma estrutura multimensional, por exemplo um set onde a chave seria a data e o valor seria um array com os elementos daquela seção.

Comment: Exatamente preciso que na section tenham n mensagens, ai neste caso o seu exemplo não vai atender mas a lógica foi boa.

Comment: Aí você vai precisar uma estrutura multidimensional. Quando o view controller é criado você pode percorrer a estrutura de dados atual e montar uma nova conforme as necessidades dessa tela. Uma solução simples é usar tuplas, ex:  var notifications = [(Date, [NotificationItem])](), notifications[section].0 pra acessar uma determinada seção e notifications[section].1[row] acessa o objeto NotificationItem pra montar cada célula